# Trying to write a loop to replace letters in a string with letters from a different string at the same index, but loop is ending early

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working on a program that is supposed to take a key as an input argument, and encrypt a user input word using this key.

The program should:

1. Ask the user for a plaintext word to encrypt
2. Standardize the letter case
3. Take each letter from the plaintext and find the index of this letter (A = 0, B = 1,...)
4. Look at the letter indexed at this location in the key string (input argument)
5. Assign this encrypted letter to a new sting called cypher
6. Print the new cyphertext string.

The code I'm using is this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    //Check that key has 26 letters or end program
    string key = argv[1];
    if (strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Get plaintext
    string plain = get_string("plaintext: ");

    //Make key all letters upper case
    for (int i = 0; i < plain[i]; i++)
    {
        if (islower(plain[i]))
        {
            plain[i] = plain[i] - 32;
        }
        printf("%c", plain[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

//Encrypt
    int index[] = {};
    int cypher[] = {};

    //Cycle through the letters in the word to be encoded
    //printf("cyphertext: ");
    printf("%c\n", key[79 - 65]);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plain); i++)
    {
        printf("index in key: %i\n", plain[i] - 65);
        cypher[i] = key[plain[i] - 65];
        printf("cypher: %c\n", cypher[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Everything executes fine until the fourth loop of the for loop that assigns the new values to the cypher string. When the program tries to set i = 4, I get the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I was expecting the last for loop to loop once for each letter of the input (e.g. input: hello; loops: 5), but I found that it stops at 4 and only outputs: 'HELL'.

I tried:

- Words with 4 characters - executes the correct number of loops, but I still get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` after the final loop
- Words with 3 characters - executes fine, no error
- Words with 5+ letters - Still loops 4 times before error

Please help!

Comment: It's odd that you'd use `islower` but not `toupper`. You don't need to check `islower` if you use `toupper` either, It either returns the uppercase letter of what's passed in or the original value. Both `int index[] = {};` and `int cypher[] = {};` are 0 length arrays. You can't read from or write to them. You need to give them an appropriate size. Instead of magic numbers like 64 use `'A'`, it makes your code more readable and understandable.

Comment: I updated: int index[10] = {}   and it seems to be working for at least 5 letters. Ultimately I want to make the length of index = to the length of the input text, but when I try to use int index[strlen(plain)] = {}; it gives error: variable-sized object may not be initialized...  any idea how I can get it to the right size? also it doesn't seem to matter that index is initialized empty like that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Considering that you don't use `index` anywhere I can't imagine that helped much.

Comment: Well that would explain why the size of that doesn't matter haha I rewrote this a couple times, so I guess I accidentally left this in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop should iterate from 0 to length of plain.

//Get plaintext

```
   string plain = get_string("plaintext: ");

    //Make key all letters upper case
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plain); i++)
    {
        if (islower(plain[i]))
        {
            plain[i] = plain[i] - 32;
        }
        printf("%c", plain[i]);
    }

//*** Must allocate memory for array
//Encrypt
    int index[100] = {};
    int cypher[100] = {};

    //Cycle through the letters in the word to be encoded
    //printf("cyphertext: ");
    printf("%c\n", key[79 - 65]);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plain); i++)
    {
        printf("index in key: %i\n", plain[i] - 65);
        cypher[i] = key[plain[i] - 65];
        printf("cypher: %c\n", cypher[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks! setting the length of cypher to 100 worked. Do you know if there's a way to get around using a fixed value? I want it to just be the length of the input word because I don't know how long the input actually will be.

Comment: after //Encrypt ... You can use a vector or malloc(strlen(plain) * sizeof(int))  to dynamically allocate memory for the array based on the strlen(plain).